# Show that the integral does not converge

Tags: calculus

Show that $\int_0^\infty \sin(x) \,$ does not converge.

$$\int_0^k \sin(x) \leq \int_0^k \, dx = k$$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} k = \infty$$

So this integral does not converge.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. It shows that your limit is $\leq \infty$

Comment: @ThePortakal So what would the correct solution look like?

Comment: No the integral doesn't converge

Comment: @MHW Hi. I hope that you're doing well. I've sent you a couple of messages, but am unsure if you've received them. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**big hint**
$$\int_0^k\sin(x)\mathrm d x=1-\cos(k)$$
Then $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\mathrm d x$ converge if and only if $\lim_{k\to \infty }\cos(k)$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been shown in another posted solution that $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx$ fails to converge as an improper Riemann Integral.

And clearly we have $\int_0^\infty |\sin(x)|\,dx=\infty$ and hence $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x)\,dx$ fails to exist as a Lebesgue integral.

However, if we interpret the integral as a Fourier Sine Transform then writing the sign function as $\text{sgn}$ and the Heaviside Function as $H$ gives

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx&=\frac1{2i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x)(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{2i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sgn}(x) e^{ix}\,dx \\\\
&=\frac1{2i} \mathscr{F}\{\text{sgn}\}(1)\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

So, while $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx$ fails to exist as either a Riemann Integral or a Lebesgue Integral, if we more broadly interpret the integral as a [DISTRIBUTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), then we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx\sim1$$

Comment: Because you didn't answer the actual question?

Comment: @math_qed Read again!  I wrote "So, while the integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx$ fails to exist as either a Riemann Integral or a Lebesgue Integral ..."  So what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And Happy New Year! ;-)

Comment: For me the answer is ok! I upvoted it in fact. Happy new year too.

Comment: @math_qed Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @MHW Hi. I hope that you're doing well. I've sent you a couple of messages, but am unsure if you've received them. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)